# Export query result in Pervasive to txt / csv file

Tags: export, pervasive, pervasive-sql

I'm using **Pervasive 10** with **PCC** (Pervasive Control Center) and I need to export a lot of results (over 100 000) to a TXT file.
I know it's possible "Execute in Text" but this feature does not work for me because after exporting about 20 000 records the program stops. 
I have also changed the settings in PCC (*Windows->Preferences->Text Output-> Maximun number of rows to display = 500,000*).

Anyone know a way to export my query result to a txt file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use the Export Data function.  Right click on the table name in the PCC and select Export Data.  From there, you can either execute the standard "select * from " or make a more complex query to pull only the data you need.  You can set the delimiter to Comma, Tab, or Colon.

Comment: We find that export doesn't properly escape quotation marks that are in the data.  Is there a setting somewhere to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Nice answer mirtheil, was wondering about this my self as well.

To add something to the answer.

It does not matter which table you right click and choose "Export Data" on, Because your query will override the default table query.